# How to bind a request model in WebAPI GET request with route attribute?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, get

```
GET :http://www.Example.com/Api/1/0/Book/Company/0 

[Route("{UserId}/{Category}/books/{BookType}/{Page}")]
        [HttpGet]
        [RequestAuthorization]
         public Response Get(int UserId,string Category, string BookType,int Page )
        {          
            var books= this.contentService.GetUserItems(UserId,Category, BookType, Page)
            return new Response() { Status = ApiStatusCode.Ok, Books = books};
        }
```

The above code works well for me.

My question is  is it possible to bind a request model in GET request ?

for example I have a request model like this

```
 public class BookbRequestModel
    {
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public int Category { get; set; }
        public int Page { get; set; }  
        public string BookType { get; set; }       
    }
```

and i want my get request  like this

```
GET :http://www.Example.com/Api/1/0/Book/Company/0 

to bind the data to my request model


[Route("{UserId}/{Category}/books/{BookType}/{Page}")]
        [HttpGet]
        [RequestAuthorization]
         public Response Get(BookbRequestModel book )
        {          
            var books= this.contentService.GetUserItems(book.UserId,book.Category,book.BookType,book.Page)
            return new Response() { Status = ApiStatusCode.Ok, Books = books};
        }
```

I tried this , but every time i get null in my book  (BookRequestModel )

Answer (score 12, accepted):

add [FromUri] and try again as below

```
[Route("{UserId}/{Category}/books/{BookType}/{Page}")]
            [HttpGet]
            [RequestAuthorization]
             public Response Get(([FromUri] BookbRequestModel book )
            {          
                var books= this.contentService.GetUserItems(book.UserId,book.Category,book.BookType,book.Page)
                return new Response() { Status = ApiStatusCode.Ok, Books = books};
            }
```

for more information :-

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/2b481f/parameter-binding-in-Asp-Net-web-api/

Comment: I'm wondering can you have part of the model `FromUri` and part `FromBody`?
I have a problem where I have a `FromBody` model and a string, the model is validated and I can check the `ModelState`, but I have to validate the string on it's own.
Can the ParameterBindingAttribute be placed on the properties inside the model?

Answer (score -3):

It takes the parameters as they are you cannot do this. I would suggest try changing routeConfig.
Add a new route. in `WebApiConfig.cs`.

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "NewApiRoute",
                routeTemplate: "myapi/{Controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = new object()//this is to make it generic you can pass object of your class also }
                );
```

Comment: Please, if you do not know the answer, at least read the other answers.