# Model null when use Route attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, routes

In my `WebAPI` I have model

```
 public class ListRequest 
 {
    public int Skip { get; set; } = 0;
    public int Take { get; set; } = 30;
 }
```

My action is

```
 [HttpGet]
 [Route("api/users")]
 public IHttpActionResult Get([FromUri] ListRequest request) {
    ...
 }
```

I need to have possibility to not pass any query parameters, then default values should be used. But, when I go to `http://localhost:44514/api/users` the `request` is null. If I remove `[Route("api/users")]` then `request` is not null and has default values for parameters.

How can I reach that behavior with Route attribute?

Comment: Why do you have the `ListRequest request` parameter when your not passing any query string values? (you may as well just initialize a new instance in the method)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I'm not passing any parameters when I want to use default parameter values. Before I add attribute everything works fine, but I need use that attribute

Comment: You may try using [HttpPost] method to pass a model in the request as a parameter.

Comment: @DalvinderSingh No, it is GET. Model used for filtering, some time other model can has over 5 properties to filter. So I just want GET with filter. And I use model instead of many parameters of action

Comment: You can find similar question like this here.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24075892/how-to-bind-a-request-model-in-webapi-get-request-with-route-attribute

Comment: @DalvinderSingh But I've already had FromUri

Comment: @DalvinderSingh thank for your help and advices. I solved that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to init model using Route attributes try

```
Route("api/users/{*pathvalue}")]
```

Comment: This worked for me but I would like to understand why

Answer (score 0):

Create your method on **post** request basis. Get type always receive null value.

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/users")]
public IHttpActionResult Get([FromUri] ListRequest request) {

}
```

**Change to**

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/users")]
public IHttpActionResult Get([FromUri] ListRequest request) {
...
}
```

Because Model (Class) type parameter does not support get type request.

*Hope it will help*.

Comment: I can't change it. Model used for filtering, some time other model can has over 5 properties to filter. So I just want GET with filter. And I use model instead of many parameters of action

Comment: anything else. Get request wont support model type parameter. You need to change according to request basis not your requirement basis.

Comment: Why? Where did you find that Get request wont support model type parameter. I always use it. And see the question. It works but only without attribute

Comment: Also you can see the comment below the question. We have already talk about that with DalvinderSingh. So your answer is not helpful. sorry

Answer (score 0):

Use data annotation. For more information visit [Default value in mvc model using data annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23823103/default-value-in-mvc-model-using-data-annotation/23823151)

**Change**

```
public class ListRequest 
{
    public int Skip { get; set; } = 0;
    public int Take { get; set; } = 30;
}
```

**To**

```
    public class ListRequest 
    {
        [DefaultValue(0)]
        public int Skip { get; set; }
        [DefaultValue(30)]
        public int Take { get; set; }
    }
```

It works without removing [Route("api/users")] and request will not be null.